# Let $E \subset \mathbb{Z}$ be non-empty, bounded below. Prove that $\inf{E} \in E$

Tags: analysis

I know that since $E$ is non-empty and bounded below that $\inf{E}$ exists, but I'm not sure how to show that it is in $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E$ is bounded below, we know that $\inf E > -\infty$.

Now assume for contradiction that $\inf E$ is not in $E$.

If $\inf E$ is integral then $\inf E +1$ is a greater lower bound than $\inf E$, contradicting the definition of infimum.

If $\inf E$ is not an integer then $\inf E = k - f$, for some integer $k$ and $f \in (0,1)$. By definition, $\inf E$ is the greatest lower bound of $E$. Note that since $E \subset \mathbb{Z}$, $k$ is a lower bound of $E$ that is greater than $k-f$. This is contradictions the definition of infimum, so that $\inf E$ must be in $E$.

Alternatively, this follows from the Well Ordering Principle
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle
by adding a constant integer $x$ so that $E+x \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and showing that $\inf \{ E+x \} = \inf \{ E \} +x$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $E$ is bounded below, $p\equiv\inf E$ is finite. Then $q\equiv \lfloor p\rfloor \in \mathbb Z$ has the property that $p\in[q,q+1)$. If it were the case that $p\in(q,q+1)$, the there would exist an element of $\mathbb Z$ in $[p,q+1)\subset (q,q+1)$, which is false. Thus $p\in[q,q+1)\setminus(q,q+1)=\{q\}\subset \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close to the infimum of a set with a convergent succession $x_n$, this succession has values in $\mathbb Z$ so it must be constant after some $n$

Answer (score 0):

There exists a non-increasing sequence $e_n \in E$ such that $\lim_n e_n = \inf E$. We have $e_n \ge \inf E$ for all $n$, and since $e_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $e_n \ge \lceil \inf E \rceil \ge \inf E$ for all $n$. Hence $\lceil \inf E \rceil$ is a lower bound, and hence $\inf E = \lceil \inf E \rceil$.

Since $e_n \to \lceil \inf E \rceil$, we have some $N$ such that $e_n = \lceil \inf E \rceil$ for all $n \ge N$. In particular, $\inf E = \lceil \inf E \rceil = e_N \in E$.